# ObjectiveC setting image when thread finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uibutton, thread-safety

I have a button which I'm trying to set the image for when a thread is finished. My code may seem useless to just change the image button but this is for practise and going onto a bigger thing.

**Goal**: Set the image for the b0 as `button_x.png` (found in the project).

**Issue**: The button image is not changing, if I make a connection between the button found on the storyboard to the viewController button declaration I get a crash with `-[UIButton setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b4c270`.

Thank you.

**ViewController.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *b0;
    Game *instanceOfGame;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *b0;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Game *instanceOfGame;

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize instanceOfGame;
@synthesize b0;
static NSString *postName = @"123";


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(post:) name:postName object:nil];
    instanceOfGame = [[Game alloc] init];
    [instanceOfGame start];
}

- (void) post: (NSNotification *) result {
    NSNumber *str = [result object];
    if (str == 0) {
        [self.b0 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage: ) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_x.png"] waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**Game.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Game : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *choice;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNotificationCenter *ns;
    -(void) start;
    @end
```

**Game.m:**

```
#import "Game.h"

@implementation Game

NSNotificationCenter *ns;
@synthesize ns;
@synthesize choice;
static NSString *postName = @"123";

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        ns = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) start {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadData) withObject:Nil];
}

-(void) loadData {
    choice = 0;

    [ns postNotificationName:postName object:choice];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIButton doesn't have a setImage: function, hence the exception being thrown.

It does have this function though:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Try replacing:

```
[self.b0 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage: ) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_x.png"] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

With a similar sort of implementation done using GCD calling the correct function:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.b0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
});
```

Comment: Wow, awesome thanks! Do you mind explaining the difference between dispatch_async and what I had if it isn't to much trouble?

Comment: Sure! dispatch_async and dispatch_sync are two commands that let you send the code inside to another thread. In the example above, I'm sending the code in the block (the part inside the ^{ }, blocks are another feature of Obj-C) to the main thread (dispatch_get_main_queue()).I used dispatch_async here, but the difference between sync and async is sync will wait for the code inside to complete, async will not. It's basically the equivalent to waitUntilDone.

Comment: A recent edition of objc.io carried couple of good pieces on [thread-safe class design](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/thread-safe-class-design.html) and [common background practices](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html). For long-running operations, you typically create a queue with `dispatch_queue_create` and submit your task in that queue with `dispatch_async`. When the result is available, you should use `dispatch_async` and update the user interface with the main thread using the main queue (obtained with `dispatch_get_main_queue`).

Answer (score 2):

@Colin Cornaby saying write.

UIButton doesn't have setImage method.

You can also use the same existing code. just update below line

```
[self.b0 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage: ) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_x.png"] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

as

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage: ) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ListDropDown.png"] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and then define method setImage:

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    [self.bo setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (str == 0) {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.b0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
    });
}
```